# Can't view Yahoo Mail emails from browser that I can view progammatically

Tags: email, imap, yahoo-mail

This one likely is a cross between superuser and StackOverflow, but I ask it from a user's perspective.

I have altered a python module to read email from yahoo.  It tries imap.mail.yahoo.com to get its messages from.  I can get the messages and read them all just fine from within my program.

I added to this module, the capability to delete certain messages which have certain wording in the subject line.  I do a call like `store(email_id, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')` which marks the message as such.  I don't do anything else like expunge or empty trash, that is the lone way I mark the message.

Now when I rerun my program, I still see such messages being retrieved.  When I log in with my browser, I see no traces of the message in inbox or trash.  I do search and advanced search (I have seen others recommend advanced search for messages that strangely disappear) and I still do not see these messages.

Where are these messages and how can I access them from my browser?  Is there some kind of hidden folder or filter storing these messages.  I really would like to know where they are so that I can either delete them for good (to improve the runtime of my program) or to store them somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some provider, flagging a message as `\Deleted` only mark it as deleted. It won't be deleted before you manually issued [EXPUNGE command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18987703/3604386).

1. When your IMAP client retrieve the messages again, it still fetch marked messages because you haven't deleted them.
2. In the other side, looks like Yahoo mail interface was configured to hide the message that marked as `\Deleted` *and AFAIK it is default configuration on ALL mail client*.